# Enable port RA0 as input and retrieve value LDR from led

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, microprocessor

I'm using the picdem 18F4550 with microchip v8.63 with the C18 compiler.

I will enable PortA to set as input, I will connect a LDR on port RA0. Which is as following (I think):

```
TRISAbits.TRISA0 = 1; //<= set RA0 as input.
```

Now I want the value of the LDR (voltage/value if a led is on), can I say:

```
int colorLed = PortAbits.RA0;
```

And now in the variable of type int there is the value/voltage of my Led.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, lets check that you have connected your LDR up correctly, it should be something like this...

[image: LDR wiring]

To read the value of PIN RA0/AN0, you need to do some initialisation to make sure the port is setup correctly. The [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39632c.pdf) explains how all this works, but these values should work:

```
TRISAbits.TRISA0 = 1;           // Set RA0/AN0 to input
ADCON0           = 0b00000000;  // Set channel select to AN0
ADCON1           = 0b00001110;  // Configure RA0/AN0 as analogue
ADCON2           = 0b10101010;  // Right justified result
                                // TAD 12 and FOSC 32 - may need to adjust this
                                // depending on your clock frequency (see datasheet)
ADCON0.ADON      = 1;           // Enable ADC
```

Now the port should be set up, you can now read the LDR value:

```
ADCON0bits.GO    = 1;           // Set the GO bit of the ADCON0 register to start
                                // the conversion.

while (ADCON0bits.GO);          // Wait until the conversion is complete.
```

You can now read the result of the LDR as a 10-bit value in `ADRESH:ADRESL`. If you only need 8-bit resolution, then set `ADCON2.ADFM = 0` for left justification of the result, then you only need to read the `ADRESH` to get your result.

Comment: the plan that you signed, correct. The code that you write is what I wanted! Many thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 5):

To read an analogue voltage you need to use the PIC's ADC (Analogue to Digital Converter).

Here's a tutorial: http://www.roboticsguy.com/tutorials/pic-microcontrollers/configuring-the-pic18f4550-10-bit-adc-module